# PHP FOR loop included function not refreshing

Tags: php, for-loop, include

We have a `for` loop that extracts the value for `$bid` from a string and then include an external file that uses that data.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $gstcnt; $i++) { {
  $bkng = explode('|', $payfor[$i]);
  $bid = $bkng[0];
  $changeslist .= $bid.' - '.$bkng[1].' '.$bkng[2].'<br>';
  include_once('/path/to/update.php');
}
```

The **update** file uses the `$bid` value to select an encrypted json file, decrypt the data, find a specific value, add data to it and then encrypt the resultant new json and save it.

The issue is that the **update** reuses the initial `$bid` value for each iteration of the loop, rather than the new value. So it keeps adding the new data multiple times to the first file, rather than once to each individual file.

I know the `for` loop is working properly, as the `$changeslist` shows each successive `$bid` value.  And **update** does what is expected, except for the mentioned issue.

I have tried both `include` and `include_once` in the loop.  I have tried `unset($bid)` in both the loop after the include and also at the end of **update**.

Unfortunately since **update** is protecting sensitive customer data, I can't post the code here.

Comment: `$changeslist .= $bid.' - '.$bkng[1].' '.$bkng[2].'<br>';` <--- Should it be `=` instead of `.=` by any chance. Also, a better way is to include the update file once above the for loop and simply call the function of that file that does the rest passing `$bid` as a parameter to it.

Comment: @nice_dev - the `.=` is correct, as there are multiple `$bid` to be dealt, plus starting and ending strings for changeslist.

Comment: Ok, so can you wrap everything inside a function in the update file and just call that function in your for loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another way ... a bit more elegant of doing this

```
// in your update.php file.
function update($bid)
{
    // ... your code ... 
}


// in your 2'nd file
require_once('/path/to/update.php');

for($i = 0; $i < $gstcnt; $i++) { {
    $bkng = explode('|', $payfor[$i]);
    $bid = $bkng[0];
    $changeslist .= $bid.' - '.$bkng[1].' '.$bkng[2].'<br>';
    update($bid);
}
```

Comment: Will give this approach a try.